# Set authentication on Apache server with openshift

Tags: apache, authentication, openshift

I read this http://www.apacheweek.com/features/userauth and I try to accomplish the same in Openshift but i don't know how.

Im using rhc and I tried to connect across ssh to my app, but I don't have permissions to use `sudo su` so I can't continue.

For example when I try to create the file `nano /usr/local/etc/httpd` I can't because I don't have root privileges.

```
> ls -la /usr/local/etc
total 20
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 jun  5 20:58 .
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 dic 11  2013 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1807 may 19 15:23 oom-kill-disable.conf
-rw-------.  1 root root 1675 may 21 14:51 ops_file_transfer_upload_id_rsa
-rw-r-----.  1 root root  399 jun  5 20:58 partitioner_disk_definitions.yaml
```

If I have a wrong approach i would appreciate you can guide me.

**UPDATE**
As @davelopercorey suggest now I'm using .htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthUserFile ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

And adding user and his password

```
htpasswd -cb .htpasswd myuser mypass
```

Authenticating prompt is showing but my user and pass are not validating well.

I have use `whereis htpasswd` to ensure im writing the correct path and issues still persists.

Comment: Can you post the specifics of what you tried to do and what errors you got so we don't have to read that whole article and try it ourselves to see what issues you had?

Comment: I don't think that environment variable is going to work in a .htaccess file, try putting the full path to the .htpasswd file instead.

Comment: Also, you want the path to the .htpasswd file you create, not the path to the executable...

Comment: Thats what i did, use the full path, but there something to confuse me, i created the .htpasswd file in my ~/app-root/data directory but for any reason its in another. I have used whereis comand to find it.

Comment: I don't think that command is doing what you think it's doing...http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_whereis.htm, and the full path to that file is not ~/app-root/data, it's something like this: /var/lib/openshift/53ed73cf5973cab9be0004b7/app-root/data/.htpasswd, but for your application.

Comment: @davelopercorey sounds reasonable, but how i said it's not creating .htpasswd file where I specified, maybe im not using htpasswd command wrong?

Comment: you need to do htpasswd -c ~/app-root/data/.htpasswd <username>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the cartridges that supports .htaccess files (such as python or php), you can put your .htpasswd file anywhere in the file system.  I suggest placing it in your ~/app-root/data directory, then you can point to it from your .htaccess file at that location and use the authentication that you want based on the rules that you put in your .htaccess file for different file types or directories, etc.

Comment: @davelopercorey Thats what I trying now, but i have issues yet, I update the post again.

Answer (score 4):

## The final solution. Thanks to @developercorey

In openshift there is a enviroment variable called $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR, is the path of your working directory i.e. `/var/lib/openshift/myuserlongid/app-root/runtime/repo/`

I create a new enviroment variable called SECURE wrapping the folder path.

```
rhc set-env SECURE=/var/lib/openshift/myuserlongid/app-root/data --app myappname
```

Finally I connect to my app with ssh

```
rhc ssh myappname
```

And create the .htpasswd file

```
htpasswd -c $SECURE/.htpasswd <username>
```

**Note: The -c option to htpasswd creates a new file, overwriting any existing htpasswd file. If your intention is to add a new user to an existing htpasswd file, simply drop the -c option.**

.htaccess file

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthUserFile ${SECURE}/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

First connect to the server using ssh:

```
rhc ssh yourappname
```

then go to app directory:

```
cd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}
```

run the following command , and then copy the result:

```
${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}
```

and create in this directory file .htaccess:

```
nano .htaccess
```

but replace "/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/" on the previously copied, it should be in the file .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

then create .htpasswd file:

```
htpasswd -c .htpasswd yourusername
```

Then you save it.

Answer (score -1):

We can use internal *OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR* variable, so for *~/app-root/data/.htpasswd* 
in my case is enough:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication"
AuthUserFile ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```