# Configuring .htaccess for Python 2.7 cartridge on OpenShift

Tags: .htaccess, python-2.7, openshift

After several hours of searching and trial and error I believe I need some basic instructions on how to setup htaccess for root level (domain root) password authentication in OpenShift.

I am running a web.py based framework application on OpenShift using the python 2.7 cartridge. The site runs fine, but when I put an .htaccess file in my wsgi/ folder (where my app lives) i got a 500 server error.

I also would love help in understanding where to put the the .htpasswd file that is needed to validate users. There have been a couple of responses to the last part on stackoverflow, but I haven't been able to get those to work with the directory tree / setup that I have.

So in summary:
1. Where in the directory tree should .htaccess go?
2. How should I reference the .htpasswd file in .htaccess?
3. Where should I locate the htpasswd file so it persists through my application updates?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Where in the directory tree should .htaccess go?

The `.htaccess` file should go in the root directory of your repo. In other words, if I cloned my repo (nickapp) to my local machine under `/home/nick/` you should put your `.htaccess` file in `/home/nick/nickapp/`. Just be sure that it's not being ignored by Git.

> 2. How should I reference the .htpasswd file in .htaccess

This was answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25494200/1914161

> 3. Where should I locate the htpasswd file so it persists through my application updates?

See the answer above in #2